# SignalR IReconnectPolicy Example

Tags: typescript, signalr, signalr.client

I am working on a .net core app that uses SignalR.

In the javascript client, there is a HubConnectionBuilder.

One of the options is "withAutomaticaReconnect()"

The second overload of this takes a "IReconnectPolicy" which is defined like this:

```
export interface IReconnectPolicy {
/** Called after the transport loses the connection.
 *
 * @param {number} previousRetryCount The number of consecutive failed reconnect attempts so far.
 *
 * @param {number} elapsedMilliseconds The amount of time in milliseconds spent reconnecting so far.
 *
 * @returns {number | null} The amount of time in milliseconds to wait before the next reconnect attempt. `null` tells the client to stop retrying and close.
 */
nextRetryDelayInMilliseconds(previousRetryCount: number, elapsedMilliseconds: number): number | null;
```

}

But I don't get it.  How am I supposed to use this when connecting?  Am I supposed to create an object that has these properties and then pass that object to it?

Or is it a callback, and the callback will receive those parameters?

The reason I ask is that there are issues with losing connection to the Hub, and I want to make sure this is configured robustly.

This is how I currently am using this code:

```
 async connect() {
    if (!this.connection) {
        this.connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
            .withUrl("/csractivityhub", { accessTokenFactory: () => this.authService.getAccessToken() })
            .withAutomaticReconnect()
            .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Information)
            .build();
        this.connection.on("onSubscribed", this.onSubscribed.bind(this));
        this.connection.on("onPublished", this.onPublished.bind(this));
        this.connection.on("onCsrActivity", this.onCsrActivity.bind(this));
        await this.connection.start().catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
    }

}
```

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-3.1#automatically-reconnect
Scroll down to find an example with IReconnectPolicy